# Laravel how to concatenate 2 rows with same data except service data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

example table:

| Patient.id | service.id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

```
$reservations = Reservation::
        selectRaw('patients.*,services.*, reservations.id as id, reservations.*')
        ->join('patients', 'patients.id', '=', 'reservations.patient_id')
        ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'reservations.service_id')
        ->when($request->date, function ($query, $date) {
            return $query->whereDate('reservations.date', $date);
        })
        ->where('status',$status)
        ->orderBy('date','ASC')
        ->orderBy('time','ASC')
        ->paginate(5);
        $reservations->appends($request->all());
        return view('admin.reservations.manage', compact('reservations'));
```

output table:

| Patient.id | service.id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2 |

hoping that you can help me
Here's my schema of the table of reservations:

```
Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('patient_id');
            $table->foreign('patient_id')->references('id')->on('patients');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('service_id');
            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->time('time');
            $table->string('status')->default('Pending');
            $table->timestamp('cancelled_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('cancelled_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('cleared_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Can you do a `toArray()` to show what the data looks like?

Comment: See the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Add that into the `selectRaw` part of the query.